# Can a VSCode extension monitor file system changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

We need a Visual Studio Code extension that monitors a specific folder on the file system, and when the contents of the folder change, it should trigger some action.

Can an extension do that?

I suppose we need a [Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks). However, all the examples on tasks I have found deal with triggers from inside VSCode (mostly edits by the user).

I have not found any examples on background tasks that are triggered by an external event source like a network or a file system.

Comment: have you looked at the file watch API of VSC

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` and `FileSystemProvider`.

Comment: @Mark isn't `FileSystemWatcher` only for files within the currently opened solution? And `FileSystemProvider` seems to be an interface that I need to implement if I want my own file system.

Comment: @rioV8 the only thing I can find is `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(...)`, but that seems to be about files within the currently opened workspace or folder. I need to watch the file system outside of the workspace.

Comment: does Node have a file watch module?

Comment: @rioV8 yes, `fs.watch`. Can I use NodeJS directly in VSCode background tasks?

Comment: Yes, VSC is a NodeJS application

Answer (score 6):

Since VSCode 1.64.2 (Jan. 2022), `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher` is able to monitor files *outside* the current VSCode workspace!

See [issue 140693](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140693) "Test: out-of-workspace file watching from extensions".

> credits to Windows team though for implementing the best OS file watcher across all operating systems.
>
> [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) is awesome and is used by the file watcher library we use.